# Why doesn't ASP.net RadioButtonList onchange client side event trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

i have asp.net project, where i have a master-page on I include this line, to reference of the JS file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/HideDIV.js"></script>
```

In the JS file i have this function:

```
function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';

    if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonTipoUser_0') != null) {
        if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonTipoUser_0').checked) {
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonTipoUser_1') != null) {
        if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonTipoUser_1').checked) {

            document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';

        }
    }
}
```

Basically i need on this RadioButtonList, call a function on Js "hideDiv()", when a select the one Button, one div hide pass to visible.

This code is in content.

```
<div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonTipoUser" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onchange="hideDiv()">

            <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Value="1">Dome</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Emp</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Vet</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>


    </div>

    <div id="div1" style="display:none">
        <a>Charls</a>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="display:none"><a>Maris</a></div>
</div>
```

I make a debug and the error msg is

> ReferenceError: hideDiv is not defined

how i make tho the onchange="hideDiv()" call the HideDiv() function?

Bests

Comment: Have you checked if the js file is loaded correctly?

Comment: right click on your page, and now go to view page source. where you see `<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/HideDIV.js"></script>`, then click on src. and check it is attached or not

Comment: yes the file is loaded.

Comment: Open the console and enter `hideDiv()` and see what that does.  If that doesn't work then the function is out of scope for some reason - maybe defined inside an enclosure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you use jquery for achieving your task

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonTipoUser" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">

            <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Value="1">Dome</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Emp</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Vet</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>


    </div>

    <div id="div1" >
        <a>Charls</a>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" ><a>Maris</a></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#div1').hide();
        $('#div2').hide();
        $('#RadioButtonTipoUser_1').on('change', function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#div1').show();
                $('#div2').hide();
            }
        });
        $('#RadioButtonTipoUser_2').on('change', function () {
            alert("ok1");
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#div1').hide();
                $('#div2').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I tested with the ` $('#div1').hide(); $('#div2').hide();` and  Jquery run.
But the rest of code not show the div.

Comment: where you test it? at your project or on js fiddle.

Comment: ok i am updating my asp:radio button into input type radio this is http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/43/

Comment: Ty, i change to literal. best

Answer (score -2):

Our site was an intranet, and I had to turn off *Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View* in Internet Explorer for onchange to work in RadioButtonList. It appears that ASP.NET actually adds a javascript event to the containing table that a RadioButtonList  renders as, and IE in Compatibility View stops that working.

[image]