# Calling Javascript from RadioButtonList onchange/Onclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a radiobuttonlist on whose change event I want to change the watermark text in a textbox.

But I am not able to call Javascript function from RadioButtonList and also not able to retrieve the value of the selected field.

Below is the code for the same.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbSelectType" runat="server" CssClass="radioButtonList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbSelectType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" Text="Auto Generate"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Manually Generate"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: could you please add you code?

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Comment: I am trying but its not letting me post the code. I have used simple RdioButtonList on aspx page in asp.net

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please display the relevant source code, thank you.

Comment: `<asp:RadioButtonList>` is ran at server runtime. If that's what you are doing....?

Comment: @Harshit, if the system does not allow you to post your code, please make sure that code is properly formatted before hitting the Save button.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292399/call-javascript-funcion-on-radiobuttonlist-onchange-asp-net

Comment: I've edited to include the \` backticks to show the code....

Comment: @BarrieReader Yeah you realise you should be using four spaces for code blocks? Back-ticks are for in-line code. [Revised edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32050870/6) Also this has nothing to do with Classic ASP and any edit comments should be made inside the edit not left on the question.

Comment: @Lankymart - understood, thanks for the heads up. I didn't mean to add ASP to the tags, I thought I deleted it.